# Need some advice on implementing a HDFS file storage solution for drupal

Tags: files

We are looking into using [HDFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hadoop) to store our files users upload through the drupal Site. I have not been able to find a module that claims to do this already so we thought we would build one. So my question is 2 folds.

1. Is anyone aware of a module that could do this?
2. Is there a specific API standard to build this out of drupal? Is it just a matter of implementing a  HDFSStreamWrapper

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for [Writing stream wrappers](https://drupal.org/node/560424) by any chance?

Comment: Also could the services http://bigdatadrupal.com/ provide be useful for this?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any existing module for that, but you could start with [storage_api](https://drupal.org/project/storage_api) and extend it by your custom implementation for HDFS.

Comment: Thanks for the response, as you mentioned we will are implementing one using storage api.